# How to store a wifi password?

Tags: wi-fi, password, lg-optimus-one

My previous phone was saving automatically my wifi password.  I now have a LG OPTIMUS L1 II, but it is asking for the password each time.

Is there a way to tell them to save it?

Comment: It recorded the password the third time I typed it.  I have no idea why it did not record it the first two time.

Answer (score 0):

The phone should automatically remember all previous connected wi-fi networks. Please verify these steps :

- When you disconnect from the network and it is not within reach will it remain in the networks list ?
- When you connect to the network and tap the network is there a button that says "Forget network " or alike ?